# Vuforia + gamekit + blender

Tags: android, augmented-reality, gamekit

https://github.com/airgames/vuforia-gamekit-integration
Could you talk me how use these sources?

I want to load a 3d model (for example, from blender) and show it when image targets is detected. I try to use these sources, but i can't understand how to use `libogrekit.so` in `imageTargets` sample, i can call `System.loadLibrary("ogrekit")` in `ImageTargets.java`, but how could i load 3d model in blender format? Teapot in the default example is loaded in cpp code.